# Credentials on Laravel

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, symfony1

In symfony 1 or 2, we can use the security for credentials, such as

Example of credentials:

- superuser : Access to admin panel, able to use CRUD, reporting.
- clients : Only for viewing of tickets.
- agent : Access only on adding, editing tickets.

We can set the whole module or a certain function for each credential access. This is to prevent anonymous users to access the page.

Example: the agent could only use route(tickets/new) and route(tickets/edit), while he/she knew that there is route(admin/main) that should only superuser can access. The security prevent the agent to access the route(admin/main) because of lock of credentials.

My question is, how could we achieve this kind of features in Laravel Framework? what are the plugins or ways without (HARD CODING) to support this kind of security features.

Answer (score 3):

**Here are some packages that do what you want:**

http://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry

https://github.com/Toddish/Verify-L4

https://github.com/Zizaco/confide

http://packalyst.com/packages/package/machuga/authority-l4

**Or you could build you own with these tutorials:**

https://medium.com/laravel-4/laravel-4-acl-a7f2fa1f9791

http://ollieread.com/blog/2014/03/18/a-simplified-laravel-acl/